# python remove lines from text that contain NA

Tags: python

I have data at http://people.stern.nyu.edu/ja1517/data/marketing.data, which I've saved as marketing.data.txt

I want to remove lines that contain NA. I wrote a 6 line python script, but it isn't working.

Can anyone point out my mistake?

```
import re
f = open('marketing.data.txt')
g = open('marketing_complete.txt', 'w')
for line in f:
    if re.search('NA', line) is None:
        g.write(line)
```

I know this hasn't worked because I tried the following at the command line.

```
grep 'NA' marketing_complete.txt | wc -l
```

which returns 3... :(

Comment: BTW, regular expressions are overkill for this - you can just do `if 'NA' not in line:` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `re`  to do this:

```
f = open('marketing.data.txt')
g = open('marketing_complete.txt', 'w')
for line in f:
    if 'NA' not in line:
        g.write(line)
```

It is good practice to open files with context managers:

```
with open('marketing.data.txt') as f:
   with open('marketing_complete.txt', 'w') as g:
       for line in f:
           if 'NA' not in line:
               g.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.  I was aware that I could grep this, but I wanted to do it in python, which because the script contains other analysis.  I've selected this answer because I'm happy to learn how to do this without re!

Answer (score 3):

You can grep it -

```
grep -v NA marketing.data.txt > marketing_complete.txt
```

Comment: dang. i was copying and pasting the file names

Answer (score 3):

If you are already grepping, just do:

```
grep -v NA marketing.data.txt > marketing_complete.txt
```

The '-v' option inverts the search so only lines that *don't* match are printed.

Answer (score 1):

For your if statement, try

```
if 'NA' not in line:
```